# How can I move and use the unused width space to the right?

Tags: html, css

I am still learning HTML and CSS and having a hard time moving the rightContentHeader beside the leftContentHeader?

Here's the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/0hnj2au5/2/).

```css
        #body .content{
            background-color: rgba(124, 76, 179, 0.6);
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            margin: 0 150px;
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px black;
            
        }

        #body .content .leftContent .leftContentHeading{
            width: 70%;
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
            margin:0;
        }

        #body .content .leftContent .leftContentHeading p, #body .content .leftContent .leftContentHeading h3{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: justify;
        }

        #body .content .rightContent .rightContentHeading {
            width: 30%;
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px red;
            align-content: right;
        }
```

```html
 
 <div id="body">
 <div class="content">
                <div class="leftContent">
                    <div class="leftContentHeading">
                        <h3>Welcome</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus consequat at ante eu consectetur. Ut finibus dictum ullamcorper. Mauris quis urna id arcu sodales egestas. Phasellus tristique efficitur risus, in accumsan massa porta ut. Duis mollis nisi non magna tincidunt faucibus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut vestibulum, lorem et tincidunt fermentum, velit tellus mollis mauris, at ultrices nisl libero faucibus velit. Pellentesque eget nisl in eros hendrerit placerat ornare quis turpis. Proin tempor ante elit, eu cursus mi consectetur eu. Maecenas quis fermentum sem, vitae porta erat. Cras gravida rutrum pretium. Fusce luctus iaculis nisl, vitae sodales lacus eleifend id.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="rightContent">
                    <div class="rightContentHeading">
                        <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
```

Comment: please do a 3min effort to place the code within the question and create a snippet instead of finding workaround to bypass the warnings

Comment: Please go read [ask], and [mcve]. That you present a minimal example of your problem by including the relevant code _directly_ into your question, is one of the basic requirements on this site.

Comment: Reduce the code to a minimal one and add more description ... also please don't assume that I downvoted, I am already helping you by commenting

Comment: You specified widths of 70%/30% for the elements _inside_ `.leftContent` and `.rightContent` only, but those two elements themselves are still a 100% wide. And even if you applied the widths to those outer elements, they would still be below each other - because divs are block elements by default. This is really quite basic stuff - perhaps you should go read some beginner’s tutorials first?

Comment: My apologies @TemaniAfif if I assumed that you down voted the question.

Comment: @misorude I am still on Tutorials and I haven't completed it yet. I am following a tutorial and trying to get it done on my different own way instead of sticking to what has been thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. One is to use css flex box.

Example code:

```css
.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: rgba(124, 76, 179, 0.6);
}

.leftContent {
    flex: 3;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}

.rightContent {
    flex: 1;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px red;
}

.leftContent, .rightContent {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="leftContent">
            <div class="leftContentHeading">
                <h3>Welcome</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus consequat at ante eu consectetur. Ut finibus dictum ullamcorper. Mauris quis urna id arcu sodales egestas. Phasellus tristique efficitur risus, in accumsan massa porta ut. Duis mollis nisi non magna tincidunt faucibus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut vestibulum, lorem et tincidunt fermentum, velit tellus mollis mauris, at ultrices nisl libero faucibus velit. Pellentesque eget nisl in eros hendrerit placerat ornare quis turpis. Proin tempor ante elit, eu cursus mi consectetur eu. Maecenas quis fermentum sem, vitae porta erat. Cras gravida rutrum pretium. Fusce luctus iaculis nisl, vitae sodales lacus eleifend id.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rightContent">
            <div class="rightContentHeading">
                <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```